# Power BI DAX measure returns duplicates after selecting values from another table

Tags: powerbi, dax

My problem concerns a measure in PBI DAX with the goal to return the result of:

1 - "the row value of the column price" / "the row value of the column budget"

To achieve this, I wrote the following code:

[notworkingRevenue] =
1 - DIVIDE([Measure Price], [Measure Budget])))
The measures [Measure Budget] and [Measure Price] are simple sums of the regarding columns.

It works fine until I activate the measure and display columns from another table in the visual.
It works as long as I display only columns and measures of table Contracts

[pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8PP2.png)

or columns of both tables and the measure mentioned above  without the "1 - " in front of it, defined as:
[workingRevenue] =
DIVIDE([Measure Price], [Measure Budget])))

[pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtGIi.png)

But creates duplicates as soon as I display columns from both tables and the measure [notworkingRevenue).

[pic3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyTGC.png)

Since I'm new to stackoverflow, I can't share a link of my data. But the table contracts was created with the model m code:

```
let
    projectList = List.Generate(() => 1, each _ <= 100, each _ + 1),
    contractsList = List.Generate(() => 1, each _ <= 1000, each _ + 1),
    priceList = List.Transform(List.Repeat(projectList, 100), each Number.RandomBetween(50, 1000)),
    contractsTable = Table.FromColumns({
        contractsList,
        List.Repeat(projectList, 10),
        priceList,
        List.Transform(priceList, each Number.RandomBetween(0.8 * _, 1.2 * _))
    }, {"ConID", "ProjectID", "Price", "Budget"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(contractsTable,{{"Price", type number}, {"Budget", type number}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

and the Projects table with the model m code:

```
let
    projectList = List.Generate(() => 1, each _ <= 100, each _ + 1),
    projectTable = Table.FromColumns({
        projectList,
        List.Transform(projectList, each "Project " & Text.From(_)),
        List.Transform(projectList, each Number.Round(Number.RandomBetween(100, 1000)))
    }, {"ProjectID", "ProjectName", "ProjectNr"})
in
    projectTable
```